# gdb remote debugging - program crashes when stepping into a shared library

Tags: c, gdb, shared-libraries, remote-debugging, gdbserver

I cross compiled a linux targeted app on a cygwin host. The program runs ok on the target and also with gdbserver. However, when I try to step through the program it crashes whenever I step into a shared library function. The backtrace gdb prints is:

`(gdb) bt`

`#0  0x00000000004008f4 in ?? ()`

`#1  0x0000003f0380d7e4 in ?? ()`

`#2  0x00002b1373630000 in ?? ()`

`#3  0x00002b1373630590 in ?? ()`

`#4  0x00002b1373631348 in ?? ()`

`#5  0x00002b1373631888 in ?? ()`

`#6  0x0000003f03a1c510 in ?? ()`

`#7  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()`

If I set a breakpoint on the function and continues it doesn't crash.

This is hello.c:

```
void foo(int*);
int main()
{
    int a;
    foo(&a);
    return a;
}
```

compiled with *x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc -g -c hello.c*.

and foo.c:

```
void foo(int *i)
{
    *i = 2;
}
```

compiled with *x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc -g -shared -Wl,-soname,libfoo.so -o libfoo.so foo.c*.

The linking is with *x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc -Wl,-rpath,. libfoo.so hello.o -o hello*.

Comment: While it shouldn't crash, you have to compile with the -g flag to do sensible debugging - does that make a difference ?

Comment: I compiled with -g. Forgot to mention.

Answer (score 1):

I too have seen such situations, though it does not seem reproducible with your example (then again, I did not cross-compile). Nevertheless, hints for dealing with such situations...

- First of all of course, compilation with `-O0 -ggdb3` (not just -g) is advised.
- Use `LD_BIND_NOW=1 gdb hello` to disable such lazy resolution.
- If that did not help, use `b foo` in gdb and then single-step and/or continue as usual and wait for it to stop in foo.

Comment: thanks, but none of these helps (except for using 'b foo' and then continuing which always worked)

Answer (score 0):

Try to compile the shared library with the debugs flags.

Comment: I did compile it with -g. anything else I need to add?

Comment: no I meant: link the shared library with your exec with -gdb option. Plus the shared library should have been compiled with the -ggdb too. so you'l hab libfoodb.so| you'll have to download the dbg version of the library. or to compile it yourself with gcc -shared -ggdb

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't help. same results.